# react-hook-form validate that password match (failing)

Tags: react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form to validate that my password and confirm password are the same. For some reason, the form elements aren't validating. I confirmed with a console.log that the reference and the confirm password are the same, but it is failing anyways. It all seems fine, where have I gone wrong?

Code

```
const { setValue, register, getValues, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

const password = useRef({});

password.current = watch("password", "");

const selectType = watch("type", '');

<IonItem >
     <IonLabel position="floating">Password</IonLabel>
     <IonInput type="password" {...register("password", { required: 'Password is required' })}/>
</IonItem>

                            
 <IonItem >
      <IonLabel position="floating">Confirm Password</IonLabel>
      <IonInput type="password" {...register("password_repeat", { validate: value => value === password.current || "The passwords do not match" })}/>
 </IonItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the interface for `<IonInput />` is different from the one `register` expects. With the spreading of `register` you're linking an `onChange` handler to update RHF's form state of that field. `<IonInput />` uses a change handler called [`ionChange`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#events) instead.

As a rule of thumb you should use RHF's `<Controller />` when working with [external controlled components](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingControlledInputs).

```js
const { control, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

const password = watch("password", "");

<Controller
  control={control}
  name="password"
  rules={{ required: "Password is required" }}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="floating">Password</IonLabel>
      <IonInput
        value={field.value}
        ionChange={field.onChange}
        ionBlur={field.onBlur}
        onFocus={field.onFocus}
        ref={field.ref}
        type="password"
      />
    </IonItem>
  )}
/>

<Controller
  control={control}
  name="password_repeat"
  rules={{
    required: "Password is required",
    validate: (value) =>
      value === password|| "The passwords do not match"
  }}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="floating">Password</IonLabel>
      <IonInput
        value={field.value}
        ionChange={field.onChange}
        ionBlur={field.onBlur}
        onFocus={field.onFocus}
        ref={field.ref}
        type="password"
      />
    </IonItem>
  )}
/>
```